# Using a VPN, yet some websites still blocked

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall

I'm using a VPN provided from my workplace, yet I am still being blocked via the firewall at my school from accessing some sites. Is there a technical reason, why I am not able to bypass the firewall using my own computer, and vpn? I know the VPN is working correctly, as I am able to access internal sites at my workplace when using it.

I don't see how it is possible for sites to still be blocked if the firewall should not know which sites I'm visiting. Could this be an issue with the VPN itself?

Note: The VPN is a private VPN hosted by my workplace itself, if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your workplace is using split-tunneling you will only send traffic to 'internal' work addresses through the VPN tunnel.  Everything else will be sent out your normal internet connection.